# How to make custom tray icon for an application?

Tags: python, icons, system-tray

I need a custom tray icon for my application written in python. I am using the code from ubuntu wiki.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python_version

The problem is, I can not create image from file. So I assume I need the name for my icon. Something like Gtk.STOCK_HOME or "indicator-messages". I can't find any documentation how to define the name for my icon in the system.

Any DOCs? For GTK3 Python 2.7 are used in my app.

Comment: Have you read: https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkstatusicon.html

Comment: Yes but without examples I don't understand this. I create my first app.

Comment: As I understand there is no PyGTK for GTK3 instead we should use GObject like that: from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GObject

Comment: I think you have to ship an icon with the same name as the registered name of the indicator, like "indicator-messages" as you said, in the directories /usr/share/icons or ~/.local/share/icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a hack:

put the icon in your home directory and run this command.

```
$ sudo xdg-icon-resource install --novendor --size 16 my-icon.png my-icon-name
```

Than just run the code from ubuntu wiki.